# how to search array words with Doctrine DQL using bucle

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql, query-string

i'm trying to search words stored in array in this way:

```
$dql_cat =' SELECT c
                FROM FrontendBundle:Categoria c
                WHERE';

        foreach ($palabras as $palabra){    

            if ($palabra === reset($palabras)){
                $dql_cat .= ' c.nombre LIKE %'.$palabra.'%';
            }
            else{
                $dql_cat .= ' OR c.nombre LIKE %'.$palabra.'%';
            }               
        }

        $dql_cat .= ' ORDER BY c.nombre';       
        $query = $em->createQuery($dql_cat);            
        $resultados['categorias'] = $query->getResult();
```

But i get an exception with the query.

Query result:

> SELECT c
>   FROM FrontendBundle:Categoria c
>   WHERE c.nombre LIKE %carpinteria% OR c.nombre LIKE %aluminio% ORDER BY c.nombre

Query exception:

> QueryException: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 98: Error: Expected StateFieldPathExpression | string | InputParameter | FunctionsReturningStrings | AggregateExpression, got '%'

I think that is more proper to use queryBuilder to avoid mistakes but i don't know how to use it with a parameters array.

I need a solution with or without queryBuilder.

Thanks.

Comment: You should pass :paramX to query and on query object call ->setParameter('paramX', '%'.$data.'%');

Comment: Thanks @Karol, but i already know how to set parameters with queryBuilder,  what i don't know is how to do it with multiple parameters stored in array.

Comment: So use param name with key of array and iterate throug this array to set multiple expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

queryBuilder would be as follows:

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
        $qb->select('c')
            ->from('FrontendBundle:Categoria', 'c');

        foreach ($palabras as $palabra){
            if ($palabra === reset($palabras)){
                $qb->where($qb->expr()->like('c.nombre', $qb->expr()->literal('%' . $palabra . '%')));
            }                                       
            $qb->orWhere($qb->expr()->like('c.nombre', $qb->expr()->literal('%' . $palabra . '%')));
        }

        $query = $qb->orderBy('c.nombre', 'ASC')
        ->getQuery();

        $resultados['categorias'] = $query->getResult();
```

Comment: Thank you. I think this response should be marked as proper answer.

Comment: your code is not secure and prone to sql injection. Do this instead : 
$qb->where(c.nombre LIKE :palabra')
$qb->setParameter('palabra', '%'.$palabra.'%')

Answer (score 0):

To begin with `%$palabra%` should be quoted, right?:

```
    foreach ($palabras as $palabra){    

        if ($palabra === reset($palabras)){
            $dql_cat .= " c.nombre LIKE '%".$palabra."%'";
        }
        else{
            $dql_cat .= " OR c.nombre LIKE '%".$palabra."%'";
        }               
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @devilcius, i had tested and discarded this way for my own mistake to write in bad order the quotes:
`$dql_cat .= ' c.nombre LIKE "%'.$palabra.'%"';`
Thanks again.